# SVM and peaks in electricity consumption

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, prediction

I'm using SVMs, specifically [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), in order to predict peaks in electricity consumption. In the training set, each vector has 24 values, representing the accumulated kWh for each hour. The vector is labeled "peak", if the next value is defined as a peak (basic outlier detection).

Sample vectors from the training set:

```
1 1:4.05 2:2.75 3:2.13 4:1.82 5:1.5 6:2.92 7:1.78 8:1.71 9:2.1 10:2.74 11:2.75 12:2.41 13:2.38 14:2.37 15:3.57 16:2.38 17:2.48 18:2.44 19:2.35 20:2.78 21:3.03 22:2.29 23:2.41 24:2.71
0 1:2.75 2:2.13 3:1.82 4:1.5 5:2.92 6:1.78 7:1.71 8:2.1 9:2.74 10:2.75 11:2.41 12:2.38 13:2.37 14:3.57 15:2.38 16:2.48 17:2.44 18:2.35 19:2.78 20:3.03 21:2.29 22:2.41 23:2.71 24:(3.63)<- Peak
0 1:2.13 2:1.82 3:1.5 4:2.92 5:1.78 6:1.71 7:2.1 8:2.74 9:2.75 10:2.41 11:2.38 12:2.37 13:3.57 14:2.38 15:2.48 16:2.44 17:2.35 18:2.78 19:3.03 20:2.29 21:2.41 22:2.71 23:3.63 24:(1.53)<- No peak
```

The training seems fine and I get a ~85% accuracy when performing cross validation. However, when I try to classify the testing set, the predicted class labels are all the same. No peaks are discovered.

I'm using the default radial basis function and haven't changed any parameters.

Output from training.model (without the vectors):

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type rbf
gamma 0.0416667
nr_class 2
total_sv 174
rho -0.883122
label 0 1
nr_sv 122 52
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: Why the "peak" and the "not peak" samples have both labels "0"? On the other hand, Have you tried with a bigger gamma? That value seems a bit too small for the range of values in your sample data.

Comment: @Pedrom: Because the vectors are always one step ahead. The first vector is labeled 1 (peak), because the next value (the last value in the second vector) is a peak. Changing the gamma doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Sorry but I still fail to see the logic on that, if you are modeling a time series it makes sense to include the event (peak) into the pattern. In any case, your real problem is that you model is over-fitting your training set, and my guess is that would be because the parameters but you could also try to collect more data if possible. Do you only have 174 data points?